# Why the $\sigma$ algebra generated by a function $f$ is the smallest sigma algebra generated by the function on its pre-image?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

$ \sigma(X) = \{X^{-1}(B); B \in \mathscr{S}\}. $

Why this it is the smallest sigma algebra generated by X? Does it have any underlying assumptions? Or is this just a definition I should remember?

Also, I just started learning probability theory for this semester (with an engineering background) and I found myself asking a lot of "why" to many definitions, should I just memorise it since those are definition?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Why is this a $\sigma$-algebra? Or are you asking why it makes sense?

Comment: A definition can't be true of false, this is a definition. So the question "why the definition is true" doesn't really make sense. As for the motivation for this definition, we want $\sigma(X)$ to be the smallest sigma algebra such that the given function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ (where $\Omega$ is the sample space) is measurable with respect to it. And in order for $X$ to be measurable, we by definition need this sigma algebra to contain all these inverse images. So we take the smallest sigma algebra which contains the inverse images.

Comment: @keen-ameteur why it is the smallest sigma algebra generated by f?

Comment: @Mark so I should just take it for granted?

Comment: A function $f:(S_1, \mathcal{F})\to (S_2, \mathcal{B})$ is measurable if $\sigma(f)\subseteq \mathcal{F}$. The minimal $\mathcal{F}$ for which this is true is $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(f)$. There is the small issue of verifying $\sigma(f)$ is indeed a  $\sigma$-algebra, but it doesn't seem like what you are asking about.

Comment: This is not a definition and can be proved rigorously @Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(\Omega ,\mathscr F)$ and $(\mathcal S,\mathscr S)$ be two measures spaces, and let $X:(\Omega ,\mathscr F)\to (\mathcal S,\mathscr S)$ be a function.

- **Definition 1 :** The function $X$ is measurable if and only if $$\forall B\in \mathscr S, X^{-1}(B)\in \mathscr F.$$
- **Definition 2:** Suppose that $X$ is measurable and let $\mathscr G\subset \mathscr F$ a $\sigma -$algebra (normally we call $\mathscr G$ a sub-field of $\mathscr F$). We say that $X$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathscr G$ if $$\forall B\in \mathscr S, X^{-1}(B)\in \mathscr G.$$
- **Definition 3:** We define $\sigma (X)\subset \mathscr F$ being the smallest $\sigma -$algebra that makes $X$ measurable. That mean : if $\mathscr H\subset \mathscr F$ is a $\sigma -$algebra s.t. $X$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathscr H$, then $ \sigma (X)\subset \mathscr H.$

---

- **Theorem :** Suppose that $X$ is measurable. Then,$$\sigma (X)=\{X^{-1}(B)\mid B\in \mathscr S\}.$$

---

**Proof:** Since $X$ is measurable w.r.t. $\sigma (X)$, we habe that $X^{-1}(B)\in \sigma (X)$ for all $B\in \mathscr S$. Therefore, $$\{X^{-1}(B)\mid B\in \mathscr S\}\subset \sigma (X).$$

Moreover, $\{X^{-1}(B)\mid B\in \mathscr S\}$ is a $\sigma -$algebra. Therefore $$\sigma (X)=\{X^{-1}(B)\mid B\in \mathscr S\},$$

as wished. $\Box$

Comment: What is the question ? @TJT

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I think I am gradually getting it. I am new measure theory and I wanna ask a general question. It seems that many proof in measure theory is not proving through mathematical manipulation but though layers of definition (often convoluted). Is it just me not smart enough for measure theory or is it normal that it takes longer times for beginners to read and understand things in measure theory?

Comment: No it's not you, it takes (a lot of) time to get into it... @TJT

Comment: @Surb : This was a really nice explanation. I just had one question. When you wrote the second to last expression regarding it being contained in $\sigma(X)$,  did you mean to write $S \in$ or did you mean $B \in $. You didn't use $S$ previously so I am hoping that you meant the latter. Thanks.

Comment: it's a typo, thanks for pointing out, I corrected. It's indeed a $B$. @markleeds